# How to correctly forward declare a typedef'd struct

Tags: c, visual-c++, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

What I want to accomplish: I want to use a typedef'd function pointer inside of a typedef'd struct where the function pointer takes a struct pointer as an argument (i.e. something like an 'object method' which takes a self-reference to the 'object').

I have this C code (simplified, hopefully not oversimplified):

```
typedef struct MYSTRUCT myStruct;

typedef void (*getSomething)(myStruct*);

typedef struct MYSTRUCT {
    getSomething get_something;
};

void get_property() {
    myStruct *structure = NULL;
}
```

So what I *think* I'm doing is: forward declare the struct, use that declaration in the function pointer typedef, then declare the actual struct using the typedef'd function pointer.

This code compiles with the intel compiler on linux (and seems to do the intended thing) but the Visual compiler throws an error:

> error C2275: 'myStruct' : illegal use of this type as an expression
>   see declaration of myStruct

Is there a way to make the VC accept my intended construct?

Comment: Is the `visual-c++` tag really appropriate?

Comment: I added it because the Visual compiler threw the error and in the explanation of the tag C was mentioned.

Comment: C but only the visual-c++ tag exists, no visual-c tag. I would have used visual-c had it existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.  I just realized this was not a problem of my forward declaration but rather because what I really did in my actual code was this:

```
void get_property() {
    some = assignment_statement;
    myStruct *structure = NULL;
}
```

I.e. I accidentally put my variable declaration + definition below the first code statement. So indeed, I had oversimplified my code fragment. Sorry for this.

Comment: That's one reason for writing complete examples you've _tested_ before by compiling and running (in this case, only the former, of course) and know that the simplified code reproduces the problem.

Comment: @user1573870 - Mark this as answered to close the loop. :)

Comment: I cannot accept my own answer before two days. @mafso Yes, you are right, my apologies.

Comment: @user1573870 It's been more than 2 days. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct MYSTRUCT {
    getSomething get_something;
};
```

should be

```
struct MYSTRUCT {
    getSomething get_something;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - fixed it. (Although it was not the cause of the error, but rather my stupidity was).

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MYSTRUCT;                  // Forward declare the struct
typedef struct MYSTRUCT myStruct; // define the typedef;

typedef void (*getSomething)(myStruct*);   // use the typedef;

struct MYSTRUCT {                 // define the struct
    getSomething get_something;
};

void get_property() {             // use the typedef again.
    myStruct *structure = NULL;
}

// Warning: I didn't actually compile that, and I'm going from memory.
```

Comment: Actually, I had tried that, but it didn't change anything since the original cause of the error was a different one.

Comment: My reading of C99 standard suggests that it is **not** necessary to forward declare the `struct MYSTRUCT`... the `typedef struct MYSTRUCT mystruct` is sufficient to declare an incomplete `struct MYSTRUCT` and an incomplete typedef'd type `mystruct`.  I use this a lot, so I'm **really** hoping my reading of the standard is correct !

Comment: @gmch - Quite possible.  I'm more of a C++ expert than C, and know few of the c89->c99 changes.  (And even with C++, I know C++98 better than C++11)